# convert string to array in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my recent **mvc 4** project, I store multiple image and other files (such as doc, pdf, ppt etc.) as string in my database. Now I want to show this multiple image and want to show link of other files.

For example, I store data as string in my db as like as given below:

```
 1980082_10201802177236118_516383197_o.jpg, ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions &amp;amp; Answers.pdf, Sample-1.jpg,
```

Now I want to fetch this string and show image and give the link of the other files.

Comment: Your " 1980082_10201802177236118_516383197_o.jpg, ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions &amp;amp; Answers.pdf, Sample-1.jpg,
" code is not clear. Do you store that string in db or 1 file name in one row? And where do you save files? in folder?

Comment: this is just string combine with multiple files as their string name and I store this string in one row.

Comment: Now, you want to extract that filenames as images, pdf files etc.. and  show them?

Comment: How can I extract this? This is my question

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help.First when you save in your database you have to make sure you save it with all the paths, not only the filenames. In simple In your Action:

```
 public FilePathResult GetDoc(int yourParam)
    {
       var  path= (from r in yourContext.yourTable where id == yourParam
                  select r.path).FirstOrDefault()
        //Considering that your path contains also the folder


            return new FilePathResult(path);


    }
```

In your View:
       `<img src="@Url.Action("GetDoc", "YourController", new { yourParam=Model.yourParam}) " />
 @*For a link*@
        <a href="@Url.Action("GetDoc", "YourController", new { yourParam=Model.yourParam}) ">@Model.TheNameOfYourFile <a/>`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that, it is not good idea to store that file names in one row in db. If I understood you right, to extract images and files from that rows, create a model that contains list of different file list:

```
public class RowResult
{
  public RowResult()
  {
     Images = new List<string>();
     Pdfs = new List<string>();
  }

  public List<string> Images { get; set; }
  public List<string> Pdfs { get; set; }  

  //you can add other file types here
}
```

Create a method that return result for every row:

```
public RowResult ExtractFilesFromRow(string row)
{
    RowResult result = new RowResult();
    string[] parts = row.Split(' ');
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        if (part.TrimEnd(',').EndsWith(".jpeg")) result.Images.Add(part);
        if (part.TrimEnd(',').EndsWith(".pdf")) result.Pdfs.Add(part);
        //add others here..
    }
    return result;
}
```

And finally, to show them in view for each row you can get `RowResult` in db and fill `List<RowResult>`. In Action:

```
....
List<RowResult> list = new List<RowResult>();
foreach (string row in rows)
{
   list.Add(ExtractFilesFromRow(row));
}
...
return list;
```

In view:

```
@foreach (string result in Model)
{
  //here depends on you want
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/Images/" + result.Images[0])" />
  ....
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/Images/" + result.Images[1])" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I store multiple image and other files (such as doc, pdf, ppt etc.) as string in my database

I assume you mean you save the *file names* as string in your database.

Now let's start with the db data you shared

> > For example, I store data as string in my db as like as given below:
> >     1980082_10201802177236118_516383197_o.jpg, ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions &amp; Answers.pdf, Sample-1.jpg,

when comma seperated becomes this

- 1980082_10201802177236118_516383197_o.jpg
- ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions & Answers.pdf
- Sample-1.jpg

Now what we have here is only filenames and to "***physical path***" to where these files are stored.

So for this to work you WILL have to save the file path in the database too. Unless you have defined a path say "C:/SomeApp/MyDump/" and you are simply dumping all the files here.

In case you are then you can use that path append it with the file name and show on the UI. The file extension could help you decide what HTML to use (`<img>` or `<a>` to display image or show a download link)